# A question regarding minimum value of...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$a+b+c=2$

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$

What is The min value of $1/a+4/b+9/c$?

I have tried to use geometric shapes and aritmetic harmonic geometric means but unfortunately ı am going nowhere?

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagrange multiplier

$$f(a,b,c,k)=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{4}{b}+\frac{9}{c}+k (a+b+c-2)$$

Solve the system $f'_x=0,f'_y=0,f'_z=0,f'_k=0$

That is

$$k-\frac{1}{a^2}=0,k-\frac{4}{b^2}=0,k-\frac{9}{c^2}=0,a+b+c-2=0$$

there are $3$ solutions but only one leads to the minimum and respects constraints

$a= \frac{1}{3},b=\frac{2}{3},c= 1$ for which $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{4}{b}+\frac{9}{c}=18$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Using AM-GM:

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{abc}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{4}{b}+\frac{9}{c}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{36}{abc}}$$

Comment: You're wonderful thank you:)

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın: you are very welcome!

Comment: I can't see in what sense this is a solution. The request was for the minimum not for an inequality. The RHS is variable

Comment: @Arnaldo I got the answer $9\sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{2}}$ using your method. İs it completely wrong?

Comment: $f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{4}{b}+\frac{9}{c}\quad$ plug $c=2-a-b$ for the given condition $f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{4}{b}+\frac{9}{2-a-b}\quad$ minimum is where $f'_a=0;\;f'_b=0$ that is $\frac{9}{(a+b-2)^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}=0;\;\frac{9}{(a+b-2)^2}-\frac{4}{b^2}=0\quad$ which gives as only positive solution $a=1/3, b = 2/3,c=1\quad$ and $f(1/3,2/3,1)=18$

Comment: Thank you @Raffaele ı see now where The lagrange comes from:)

Answer (score 2):

Use Cauchy Schwarz inequality
$ (\frac{1}{a} + \frac{4}{b} + \frac{9}{c}) (a + b + c) \ge (1+2+3)^2$.

Comment: I am not very fluent about The usage of Cauchy-Schwarz. How do you legalize The factor $(a+b+c)$ is it a property of inequalities?

Comment: You can read about Cauchy Schwarz inequality here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: If you are not familiar with vector space yet. You can think of it in this way, for $a_i, b_i \ge 0, i=1, \ldots, n$, we have  $(a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n) (b_1+b_2+ \ldots+b_n) \ge (\sqrt{a_1 b_1} + \sqrt{a_2 b_2} + \ldots + \sqrt{a_n b_n})^2.$ Equality holds when $a_i = \lambda b_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: I wasn't able to get what you did but i see now very clearly thank you:)